# How to give a class instance to OpenReadAsync method?

Tags: c#

I have a list of instances, each of them has a string "Uri". I want to get some info from API for each instance of the list, and assing this info for instance's fields. But in  void c_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) I dont have access to instanse. I tried to use

```
    void cl_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
        ClassName item = sender as ClassName ;       
        XElement element = xml.Root.Element("user");     
        item.SourseFirstName = (string)element.Element("first_name").Value;
```

But I have a `NullReferentsException`.

Comment: list of instances upi mean list that contains  string "Uri".

Comment: No, list that contains instances of some class, and theese instance has a field string "Uri"

Comment: Maybe a need to add more info for my question?

Comment: with OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e you often need to download the stream

Comment: Can you give some more info, a'm a newbie)

Comment: at what part line is your exeption

Comment: problem solved via lambda expression